# How to create a modal sheet with Cocoa that has a shadow and no weird title bar?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I tried to use Cocoa sheets for the first time, but cannot achieve what I wanted. So in general I want a modal sheet that blocks all input to the underlying window and has the standard window shadow and no explicit title bar. Here is what I've got so far:

[image]

I achieved this with the following code:

```
- (BOOL)windowShouldClose:(id)sender
{
    NSRect sheetFrame = NSMakeRect(0, 0, 432, 224);
    NSWindow* window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:sheetFrame styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskBorderless backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
    [window setHasShadow:YES];
    window.backgroundColor = [NSColor redColor];
    window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true;
    QuitView* quitView = [[QuitView alloc] initWithFrame:sheetFrame];
    window.contentView = quitView;
    __block SheetController* sheetController = [[SheetController alloc] initWithWindow:_window andSheet:window];
    [quitView.noButton setTarget:sheetController];
    [quitView.noButton setAction:@selector(quitSheetAndContinue)];
    [quitView.quitButton setTarget:sheetController];
    [quitView.quitButton setAction:@selector(quitSheetAndAbort)];
    [_window beginSheet:window completionHandler:^(NSModalResponse responseCode)
    {
        sheetController = nil;
        if (responseCode == NSModalResponseAbort)
        {
            [self quit];
        }
    }];
    return NO;
}

- (NSRect)window:(NSWindow *)window willPositionSheet:(NSWindow *)sheet usingRect:(NSRect)rect
{
    return NSMakeRect(144, 336, 432, 0);
}
```

The issues I want to solve are:
1)Remove the weird gray line at the top of the sheet (can anyone explain where that comes from?).
2) The underlying window is still receiving hover events even though buttons are not clickable, can I disable that?
3) I want the sheet to have the standard window shadow, as the snippet shows, I tried to explicitly enable it but no luck.

Can anyone provide help/hints on some/all of the 3 points mentioned above?

Comment: A simple solution to all your problems is to use a view controller and present it as a sheet over another.

Comment: @ElTomato `presentViewControllerAsSheet:` seems to be available only from 10.10. Are there any 10.9 or lower OS version compatible solutions?

Comment: Your topic mentions nothing about compatibility requirement with a 4-year-old operating system or even older.  Where does it come from?

Comment: @ElTomato - it comes from the sad fact that a part of our userbase is still sitting on that 4-year-old OS.

Answer (score 1):

This is in Swift and Xcode 9.1 with storyboards,

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

    var viewController: NSViewController?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        viewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateController(withIdentifier: NSStoryboard.SceneIdentifier(rawValue: "MyModalViewController")) as? NSViewController
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {
        //self.presentViewControllerAsSheet(viewController!)
        self.presentViewControllerAsModalWindow(viewController!)

        self.view.window?.center()
    }

    override var representedObject: Any? {
        didSet {
        // Update the view, if already loaded.
        }
    }

}




 class MyModalViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBAction func buttonPressed(_ sender: NSButton) {
        dismissViewController(self)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do view setup here.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear() {

        self.view.window?.titleVisibility = .hidden
        self.view.window?.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true

        self.view.window?.styleMask.insert(.fullSizeContentView)

        self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.closable)
        self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.fullScreen)
        self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.miniaturizable)
        self.view.window?.styleMask.remove(.resizable)

        self.view.window?.isMovable = false
    }

}
```

[image: Output]

You might implement the needed style masks for the main window too. The main window are movable but putting `self.view.window?.isMovable = false`
to the ViewController viewWillAppear() to disable moving.

And in MyModalViewController before dismissViewController(self) one might enable it using `let vc = presenting as! ViewController` and `vc.view.window?.isMovable = true` before dismissing controller.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else finds this useful, I was able to get some of the things I needed with:

```
NSWindow* window = [[NSWindow alloc] initWithContentRect:sheetFrame styleMask:NSWindowStyleMaskTitled backing:NSBackingStoreBuffered defer:NO];
window.backgroundColor = [NSColor clearColor];
window.titlebarAppearsTransparent = true;
```

This gave me a window with the weird top shadow but with a window shadow. Sadly I was not able to disable hovering on the underlying window but at least no actions were executed on clicks which was kind of fine.

[image]

Comment: I thought you said you need compatibility with 10.9 (or even lower). `titlebarAppearsTransparent` is 10.10+ only.

Comment: @KenThomases oh thanks for pointing that out, I missed that. Being new to OSX development, is there a way, to actually see what are the restrictions imposed? As in running some tool that tells - your API calls limit you to 10.x or something? Or must I manually put all the SDKs on my machine and try to build against them?

Comment: If you're able to build with Xcode 9 or later (while still targeting deployment to older OSes), there's a new warning `-Wunguarded-availability` to find that. You can use the new pseudo-functions `@available()` or `__builtin_available()` to do checks for availability at runtime in a way that the compiler understands as "guarded" so it doesn't warn.

Comment: @KenThomases - thanks a lot, I'll upgrade to Xcode 9 then. Coming from Windows, this mess with the availability really seems something weird. And again thanks for pointing this out, I was able to walk switch to the textured background mask for the window.